# Set DialogFragment bottom margin according to calling activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` that gets called from 1 of 4 buttons from a certain activity. Currently I have `paddingBottom` set to `48dp` (height of these buttons) so the dialog pops up right above these buttons. But I've encountered a problem where on a really high res phone there's a gap between the dialog's bottom and the row of buttons.

Is there any way to either programmatically or through XML set the dialog right on top of calling activity button's height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve the problem with setting the `RelativeLayout` height to `fill_parent` instead of fixed `460dp` size. All of the children now use `match_parent` for height.